# Enable highlighting for autodocs-linked viewcode sections

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I recently changed my html theme in sphinx from `alabaster` to `sphinx_rtd_theme`, and there is one feature that I'm missing. When opening a code section with the viewcode extension, the linked code block will be highlighted (the yellowish background behind the linked section).

[image]

Which now doesn't happen any more:

[image]

Is there a way to enable it? I searched [here](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html) for that config option but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: To me those two screen shots look very similar. What is the problem?

Comment: the yellow background behind the linked section. Like in the python docs, if I link to [the abs function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs), then that line will be "highlighted".

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to edit rtd theme.